# Trouble translating a Child Theme

Tags: child-theme, translation

I'm having a hard time trying to use a custom translation for my child theme based on Storefront (WooCommerce)

For some reason, the translation doesn't take effect.

Here is what I did:

1. Created a `languages` directory inside the child's theme folder
2. Put the corresponding personalyzed es_ES.mo & es_ES.po files (based on
   storefront.pot)
3. Edited `functions.php` to read those files:

```
function my_child_theme_setup() {
     load_child_theme_textdomain( 'jllorentesstorefront', get_stylesheet_directory() . '/languages' );
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'my_child_theme_setup' );
```

But nothing happens, it still uses the default Spanish translations, not mine's...

Any ideas, please?
Thanks!

Comment: Are you using any plugin?

Answer (score 1):

you must have to enque your parent theme first.

```
function load_parent_stylesheet() {
 wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-styles', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_parent_stylesheet' );
```

Then load your translation folder

```
function my_theme_lang_setup() {
 $lang = get_stylesheet_directory() . '/languages';
 load_child_theme_textdomain( 'your-domain', $lang );
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'my_theme_lang_setup' );
```

Put this in your function.php and try